JQ print two arrays values using the same index
in the following example I have two arrays (timestamp and values) that are related by the same index, so timestamps[0] is related to values[0], timestamps[1] is related to values[1], ...
{"timestamps": ["1730135460000", "1730137620000"], "values" : ["15", "23"]}

I need to print each one in a row like this:
1730135460000 15
1730137620000 23

But instead I am getting:
1730135460000 1730137620000 15 23

I know this is wrong but wondering if there is a way to achieve what I am looking for
echo '{"timestamps": ["1730135460000", "1730137620000"], "values" : ["1", "2"]}' | jq -r '[ .timestamps[], .values[] ] | @tsv'

Thanks!

Put just the arrays (don't destructure them with .[]) into an outer array, and use transpose to zip them. Then, you can iterate over the result array to get the individual sub-arrays.
jq -r '[.timestamps, .values] | transpose[] | @tsv'

1730135460000   15
1730137620000   23

Demo

Created something very complex that worked, but thanks for that! echo '{"timestamps": [1730135460000, 1730137620000], "values" : [1, 2]}' | jq -r '(.timestamps | to_entries) as $ts | (.values | to_entries) as $vs | foreach $ts[] as $item (0; $item ; [ $item.value, $vs[$item.key].value ]) | @tsv'

@bajistaman If you need access to the index itself, here's a simpler way: range(.timestamps | length) as $i | [.timestamps[$i], .values[$i]] | @tsv
